# Using DisplayFor to display a table with header

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

Ok so I usually use a foreach in my view to display data in a table. I recently discovered that DisplayFor can do this for me using a DisplayTemplate. The problem is how do I create the header for the table. The following code will obviously create a header for each FooPermissionModel model:

```
    @model StackExamples.Models.FooPermissionModel
    <table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>
                    Heading 1
                </th>
                <th>
                    Heading 2
                </th>
                <th>
                    Heading 3
                </th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(x => x.Field1)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(x => x.Field2)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(x => x.Field3)
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

I could place the table header on the main view but surely there's a better way?

Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: You can set using CSS

Comment: have you initialize table with foreach loop?

Comment: I thought the point of using a DisplayFor is that you don't need a foreach loop.

Comment: Why don't you use WebGrid?

Comment: I could use a WebGrid but I'd rather not. I take it there's no way to use DisplayFor and include headers??